# xuggler give me such error please help me what i do?

Tags: xuggler

2013-06-21 07:25:59,162 [main] ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library: xuggle-xuggler; version: 3; Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle-xuggler in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary0(JNILibraryLoader.java:265)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary(JNILibraryLoader.java:168)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.(XugglerJNI.java:19)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.(IContainer.java:1457)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.(MediaReader.java:137)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeReader(ToolFactory.java:77)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.demo.GetContainerinfo.main(GetContainerinfo.java:22)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs for Library Dependency. I solved this problem by adding jars sequentially as bellow:

1) commons-cli-1.1.jar
2) commons-lang-2.1.jar
3) logback-classic-1.0.0.jar
4) logback-core-1.0.0.jar
5) slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
6) xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of reasons that could cause this on the Xuggler FAQ, these seem to be the main causes I think.

This error can occur if you are using the 32 bit version of Xuggler with a 64 bit Java JVM, or if you are using the 64 bit version of Xuggler with a 32 bit Java JVM.

It can also occur if you are using Xuggler without having it installed, which i see you're using Xuggler version 3 in that stack trace, and the no-install build of Xuggler started with version 5.3, so that's another possibility.

It could ALSO occur if you don't have your environment variables set up correctly.

You can also take a look at the [FAQ](http://web.archive.org/web/20130320025041/http://wiki.xuggle.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions) if none of those are the problem in your case.