# Xuggler: UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load xuggle-xuggler: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, audio, video, xuggler, unsatisfiedlinkerror

ive tried to convert a video into an .mp3-file an an android device.

so after a long time of seach and googleing(not sure if its called so respectively is spelled so) i've found Xuggler.
It played out as the best fitting solution, because i cant port ffmepg myself(no linux / ubuntu available) and JAVE gave me soooooo much errors. so i decided to use Xuggler.

Ive added **slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar** and **xuggle-xuggler-3.4.1012.201001312056.jar**(not 5.4 the actual version, because me android cant handle it ;() as external librarys

```
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaViewer;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;

String source = this.storagePath + "/" + this.FileName + this.Video_encoding;
String target = this.storagePath + "/" + this.FileName + ".mp3";

IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(source);
IMediaWriter mediaWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(target);
mediaReader.addListener(mediaWriter);
while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null) ;
```

I get the following errors at this line:

```
IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(source);
```

Here's my stacktrace:

```
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.<init>(MediaReader.java:137)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeReader(ToolFactory.java:77)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at at.m4tho.youtubemp3sync.Async_DL.ConvertToMp3(Async_DL.java:194)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at at.m4tho.youtubemp3sync.Async_DL.doInBackground(Async_DL.java:70)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at at.m4tho.youtubemp3sync.Async_DL.doInBackground(Async_DL.java:1)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    ... 5 more
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.<clinit>(IContainer.java:1457)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    ... 12 more
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load xuggle-xuggler: findLibrary returned null
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary0(JNILibraryLoader.java:265)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary(JNILibraryLoader.java:168)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19)
08-23 20:27:32.783: E/AndroidRuntime(19678):    ... 13 more
```

So i've wasted too mucht time searching for an alternative or some fixes, therefore i ask you. Does anybody have some ideas how to fix this?

If this happens to be a doublepost and somewere someone has asked the same thing please leave me a link.

Sorry about my bad english ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the UnsatisfiedLinkError before, and there are several posts about it that might help. But first, make sure you're using the right version of xuggler for your JVM (e.g. 32 bit xuggler for 32 bit java, 64 for 64 bit java). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237736/xuggler-give-me-such-error-please-help-me-what-i-do/23956609#23956609) post for more details.